# Solving a java Exception in reading input file

Tags: java, input

I have an input file in the following format:

```
1  // No. of test case
N Q  // N= Number of string and Q= Number of Query
a
bvcc
.
.
upto N string
3763717342424960
212
.
.
. upto Q
```

I am getting the following Error:

```
"main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3763717342424960"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

My code:

```
int t = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
while(t>0){
    t--;
    StringTokenizer sr = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine());
    int n = Integer.parseInt(sr.nextToken());
    int Q = Integer.parseInt(sr.nextToken());
    String[] S = new String[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) S[i]=in.readLine();
    while(Q>0){
        Q--;
        int index = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        Batman(index, S, L,n-1);
    }
}
```

Please Help me to solve this Issue

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this Exception is because the Maximum value is 2,147,483,647(inclusive).(2^31 -1).

I suggest you use a Long Data type.

For further information on Data Types and their sizes, refer here: [Basic Java Data Types](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_datatypes.htm)

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This number is to big for Integer.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum integer is `2147483647`

Use `long` instead of `int`

Answer (score 0):

Your string is too long for int, try Long

Long.parseLong

Answer (score 0):

The number that you are trying to parse is larger than the [maximum value an Integer can hold.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE).

As the others have suggested, try storing that number in a long instead. You can convert your String to a long using the [Long#parseLong()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String)) method.

Answer (score 0):

Use Long prarseLong because the value exceeds the limit of int.